# Angular:How to set aria-selected for option in select control for Angular

Tags: html, angular, accessibility

I have a select control with multi select true and option elements in ngFor. Now I want to set aria-selected to true if option is selected other wise to false.

Comment: You can use `[attr.aria-selected]="selected"` where selected is a boolean

Comment: I tried this way but as it is in loop this value is getting updated to all options.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you're using please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution consists in using the loop to check for each option if it is part of selected options and if yes, set `aria-selected` to `true` using angular [[attr.attribute-name]](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) template syntax.

Here is a [simple Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sasensi-multi-select-aria-selected) demonstrating this solution.
Select options and see that elements are properly postfixed (meaning that aria-selected is set to true).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p>Pick values and see that aria-selected is set to true</p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" multiple>
      <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value" [attr.aria-selected]="selectedValues.indexOf(value) >= 0">{{value}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      /* use CSS to add postfix to elements with aria-selected set to true */
      option[aria-selected="true"]::after {
        content : ' aria-selected';
      }
      `,
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  values = [
    'value 1',
    'value 2',
    'value 3',
  ];
  selectedValues = [];

  constructor() {
  }
}
```